# trigger('click') activating multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a system where you first select a date and then click the Home button and call a modal which will have a form. When clicked the button without selecting the date, it turns red and does nothing. When you select the date and click the button, it adds the parameters of modal and click again to open the form. However, the form is opened N times, locking the entire system. Can anyone help me?

HTML:

```
<div id="cidade-1256" class="col-sm-4 box-curso">
  <div class="plan wow fadeInLeft animated animated" data-wow-offset="120" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1.5s; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s; animation-name: fadeInLeft; -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;">
    <div class="title">Brasília</div>
      <div class="description">
        <ul><li><button type="button" class="btn btn-curso">AGO | 15 - 16</button></li></ul>
      </div>
      <a id="1256" class="btn btn-primary">ORDER NOW</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[id]', function(e){
    var id_form = $(this).attr('id').replace('#', '');
    var id_order = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    if($('#cidade-' + id_form).find('button').hasClass('active')){
       $(id_order).removeClass('btn-curso-error');
       $(id_order).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
       $(id_order).attr('data-target', '#modal-form');
       $(this).trigger('click');
    }else{
       $(id_order).addClass('btn-curso-error');
    }
});
```

Comment: you can use `$(this)` instead of `$(id_order)` no? I know this won't fix the issue but it will be clearer, also, try chaining them as well

Comment: seems like infinite loop, isn't it? button allways has  class active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to remove the `.active` class from the button, otherwise it causes the infinite loop you're seeing.

See the below snippet, I think that's what you're trying to achieve. Although, I probably wouldn't use the same link to link again.

Note: I had to switch `#1256` to a `button` in the snippet, you can keep it as a `a` tag.

```js
$("#1256").on('click', function(e) {
    var id_form = $(this).attr('id').replace('#', '');
    var $button = $('#cidade-' + id_form).find("button");
  
    if($button.hasClass('active')){
       $button.removeClass('active');
       $(this).removeClass('btn-curso-error')
              .attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
              .attr('data-target', '#modal-form')
              .trigger('click');
    } else {
       console.log("error");
       $(this).addClass('btn-curso-error');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cidade-1256" class="col-sm-4 box-curso">
  <div class="plan">
    <div class="title">Brasília</div>
      <div class="description">
        <ul><li><button type="button" class="btn btn-curso active">AGO | 15 - 16</button></li></ul>
      </div>
      <button id="1256" class="btn btn-primary">ORDER NOW</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You were right, the problem was in class 'active' that was entering loop.